# Visualforce apex:inputField and apex:detail with SLDS: on the roadmap or workaround?

Tags: visualforce, inputfield, slds, bootstrap

Long waiting, but seems still no support for apex:inputField and apex:detail in SLDS.

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/visualforce/

Does anyone know if that's on the roadmap or any viable workaround?

We have made a Bootstrap-layer hackish on the top of old VF-styles, but it's still incomplete and I need to decide to either finalize it or wait or dig for alternatives.

Requirement roughly is: 100% VF-features in a contemporary skin. needs not to be 100%-looking like SLDS, but must not look like aloha-retro style with the flair of 2006...